# Compute $ \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} \ln(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})\Delta(e^{-3x^2-4y^2})\,dx\,dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Compute $$ \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} \ln(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})\Delta(e^{-3x^2-4y^2})\,dxdy$$ knowing that $\Delta \ln(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})=0$ on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$.

I defined $g(x,y)=\ln(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ and $f(x,y)=e^{-3x^2-4y^2}$ and after some calculations I have found:

$$g \Delta f= \nabla \cdot (g \nabla f) - \nabla \cdot (f \nabla g)+f \Delta g$$

I don't know how to proceed. I tried using divergence theorem but I failed to apply it.

Comment: why not just explicitly calculate the laplacian and transform to polar coordinate?

Comment: @dezdichado I haven't tried; does that actually work out well? I wouldn't expect it to, but then again it could be a textbook exercise where it does. On the other hand, it if is indeed some kind of class or textbook exercise, it could be in a section about techniques such as the divergence theorem, hence the desire to use it in a solution.

Comment: it should work out, though it could be ugly. The singularity of $\ln(r)$ is handled with the extra $r$ coming from the jacobian.

Answer (score 1):

The equation

$$g \Delta f= \nabla \cdot (g \nabla f) - \nabla \cdot (f \nabla g)+f \Delta g$$

applies here with $g(x,y)=\ln r$ and $f(x,y)=\exp(-3x^2-4y^2)$. Integrating over a region $R$,

$$ \iint_R (\ln r)\Delta e^{-3x^2-4y^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$

becomes

$$ =\iint_R \left[\nabla\cdot(\ln r\,\nabla e^{-3x^2-4y^2})-\nabla\cdot(e^{-3x^2-4y^2}\,\nabla \ln r)+e^{-3x^2-4y^2}\Delta \ln r \right] \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y $$

Now, $\nabla \ln r=0$ and the other two are susceptible to the divergence theorem,

$$ = \oint_{\partial R} \left[\ln r\nabla e^{-3x^2-4y^2}-e^{-3x^2-4y^2}\nabla \ln r\right]\cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{n}$$

The integrand is $\exp(-3x^2-4y^2)$ times some other stuff, and the exponential term will dominate so we can expect this to tend to $0$ exponentially as $R$ expands. More precisely, the integral is

$$ \oint_{\partial R} \left[(\ln r)(-6x,-8y)-\frac{1}{r^2}(x,y) \right]e^{-3x^2-4y^2}\cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{n} $$

Let $\partial R$ be a circle of radius $a$, so $r=a$, the maximum of $\|(-6x,-8y)\|$ is $8a$, the maximum of $\|(x,y)\|$ is $a$, and the minimum of $3x^2+4y^2$ is $3a^2$, so this integral is bounded above in magnitude by

$$ \left( 8a \ln a+\frac{1}{a}\right)e^{-3a^2} $$

which indeed tends to $0$ as $a\to\infty$.

Comment: ,a goes to infinity or 0?

Comment: You could do that, but it would be superfluous. The smaller circle's domain of integration would have perimeter tending to $0$, so it wouldn't matter. Why bother?

Comment: In the smaller circle,normal is opposite and a goes to 0?